# Using Haskell's "eval" to evaluate an entire module instead of a single value

Tags: haskell, dynamic, eval, ghc

I've been toying with the the "eval" function provided by the [plugins package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins-1.5.4.0/docs/System-Eval-Haskell.html). It is working great for evaluating a single function.

I'm wondering, is there a way to input an entire module, and evaluate a value from that module (but allowing the value to reference other things in the module)

For example, right now I'm doing something like

```
x :: Int
  where 
    y = 2
    z = 3
    x = y+z
```

I'd like to do something like

```
module Foo where
import Bar

x :: Int
x = y+z

y = 2 :: Int
z = 3 :: Int
```

where I then use "eval" on the string and somehow get `x` back.

I could use the plugins.load functions, but I'd really like to be able to evaluate directoy from a string, instead of having to load from an object or temporary file.

Comment: How should it know you need x and not y or z?

Comment: The same way when you use Plugins.Load, you can give it a parameter of the name you're looking for

Comment: I think there is really no good way to do this directly from a string. I tried it, but it as a real mess and I couldn't even figure out how to load the module (only parse/simplify/typecheck). GHC expects to work with files, that's it.